# Redirect duplicate url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, duplicates

I have duplicate urls and i need to do some redirection in htaccess

Examples:

Original Urls are :

```
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/pacman.html  
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/nintendo.html  
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/snake.html
```

I have about 1000 games name

Example of duplicate urls :

```
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/1/pacman.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/1521/pacman.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/52154/pacman.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/abc/pacman.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/opq/pacman.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/opq/1/2/35/pacman.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/154/3562/snake.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/2541/snake.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/524/snake.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/absc/gtar/15/nintendo.html
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/nije/nintendo.html
```

I need to redirect them to original urls

So

```
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/anynumber/mygamesname.html  
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/anyword/mygamesname.html  
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/anyword/anynumber/anyword/mygamesname.html
```

Must be redirected to

```
www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/mygamesname.html
```

Comment: Is there only ONE (1) folder after `/listofgames` and before the html file? ¿Is the html file always the last one in the URL-path? ¿Is `listofgames` a fixed string? ¿Do all files to be moved have the extension `html` or the extension can be `htm` or `php`, etc.?

Comment: There is more than one folder, and yes the html is only the last one in the url path , and yes listofgames is a fixed string, and also all files have only the extension html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/listofgames/.*/([^\.]+)\.html/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*    listofgames/%1.html                    [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/any/number/of/folders/mygamesname.html`

with or without trailing slash.

To:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/listofgames/mygamesname.html`

Effectively removing the segment path between `/listofgames/` folder and the HTML file.

String `listofgames` and extension `html` are assumed to be fixed, while `mygamesname` is assumed to be variable.

The incoming URL structure has to be kept for the rule-set to work: Last string inside the URL must be the HTML file.

For silent mapping, remove `R=301` from `[R=301,L]`

Comment: Ty brother that's what i was looking for.. worked like a charm